# CodeIgniter - Login System After Login Show Data In Database

Tags: php, codeigniter

i made a login system in codeigniter, now i want to view the data from database after login user see for this i make one model but still confused what to do now, i m new in codeigniter.

This is model i make

```
<?php
Class Newsletter extends CI_Model
{
 function newsdata($name, $email, $city)
 {
   $this -> db -> select('id, name, email, city');
   $this -> db -> from('newsletter');
   $this -> db -> where('name', $name);
   $this -> db -> where('city', $city);
   $this -> db -> where('email', $email);
   $query = $this -> db -> get();

   foreach($query as $row)
{
print $row ->id;
print $row ->name;
print $row ->email;
print $row ->city;
print "<br>";
}

   }
 }
?>
```

and in view i make a file with name of home_view.php and there i use this

```
<?php $this->load->model('newsletter'); ?>
```

if any one guide me please how can i solve this.

Comment: Read [Codeigniter Documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/) !
Models shouldn't print anything! You need to read about MVC structure, how its working and etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok change your model name to **newsletter_model**. Now in your Controller:

```
<?php
Class Newsletter extends CI_Model
{
  function newsdata($name, $email, $city)
 {
    $this->load->model('newsletter_model');
    $data['result'] = $this->newsletter_model->getdetails($name, $email, $city);
    $this->load->view("home_view", $data);   
 }
}
?>
```

Now in your Model:

```
<?php 
    Class Newsletter_model extends CI_Model {

       function getdetails($name, $email, $city){
        $this -> db -> select('id, name, email, city');
        $this -> db -> from('newsletter');
        $this -> db -> where('name', $name);
        $this -> db -> where('city', $city);
        $this -> db -> where('email', $email);
        $query = $this -> db -> get();
        return $query->result();
    }
 }
 ?>
```

Now on your view page:

```
 <?php
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
      echo $row ->id;
      echo $row ->name;
      echo $row ->email;
      echo $row ->city;
      echo "<br>";
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: i already added in controller but i dont understand what i add to view in home_view.php


'class VerifyLogin extends CI_Controller {

 function __construct()
 {
   parent::__construct();
   $this->load->model('user','',TRUE);
   $this->load->model('newsletter','',TRUE);
 }'

Comment: do you want the data to be printed on your view page?

Comment: yes after sucessfull login person saw data this specific table data on home_view.php

Comment: 'A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: result

Filename: views/home_view.php

Line Number: 14'

Comment: change `$this->load->view("home_view.php", $data);` in controller to `$this->load->view("home_view", $data);`

Comment: "A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: views/home_view.php

Line Number: 14"

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
   <title>Simple Login with CodeIgniter - Private Area</title>

 </head>
 <body>
   <h1>Home</h1>
   <h2>Welcome <?php echo $username; ?>!</h2>
   <br>
   <p>Welcome In Admin Panel </p>
   
  <?php
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
      echo $row ->id;
      echo $row ->name;
      echo $row ->email;
      echo $row ->city;
      echo "<br>";
    }
 ?>
    
   <a href="home/logout">Logout</a>
 </body>
</html>`

Comment: '<?php
    if (is_array($result))
{
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
   echo $row ->id;
      echo $row ->name;
      echo $row ->email;
      echo $row ->city;
      echo "<br>";
    }
}   
 ?>'

i add this line and one error solve only one remaining.

Comment: which is remaining now?

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: result

Filename: views/home_view.php

Line Number: 14

Comment: i use newsletter_model.php in module
newsletter.php in controller 

but in both files you see two functions call one is newsdata & second in getdetails this error might be from this reason?

Comment: yes because you will first call controller funftion `newsdata` and from there the model function will be invoked which will give you theresult.Just run the code as it is you won't get error.

Comment: i use code as it is , i just ask might be its create problem thats why i still try to debug this problem at my side.

"thanks"

Comment: sir i figure out this framework need to pass out the variable so where i mention the variable $result so the whole code pass out and show the result.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use below code for your case.

```
 foreach($query->result() as $row)
```

Refer this [user guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23359014/codeigniter-banner-page-choose-file-php-errors  @user2936213 Please SuGgest